# javascript prompt get cancelled while changing tab

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have a web page, when a user clicks on a button, an email is sent with a token and a **prompt** (`prompt()` method) appears waiting the user to enter the token s.he received. However, I observed that the prompt get cancelled when switching tabs. Is it possible to prevent the prompt to get **cancelled** when changing of tabs? Otherwise I will have to use another kind of input as we receive emails most of the time through our browser. Any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What kind of prompt? Created with `prompt()`? And in which browser?

Comment: Yes, with prompt(). Doesn't matter the browser, I would like that to work in any browser. For the reward it was Vivaldi and Brave.

Comment: You’ll need to use a standard form (with `<input type="text">` or something) instead of `prompt()`, then. How it’s presented on the page is up to you.

Comment: So, there is no way to get the prompt staying active while switching tabs?

Comment: Probably not in Chrome (and apparently a lot of Chromium-based browsers). Works in Firefox, because Firefox improved its page-specific modals a while ago.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, going to get that input in another way.

Comment: Of course you can call `prompt()` again if the previous one had been cancelled (or was submitted without a value), but I'd argue that's not a good user experience.

Comment: Ok, I am going to use a form input. Thanks for your time.